# Sync Erigon to Geth

Tags: private-blockchain, synchronization, erigon

I have a geth server running on local with dev chain. I would like to sync an Erigon node with the geth server. I tried passing the geth enode address as staticpeer to the Erigon server but the syncing isn't working.

Comment: Can you provide more details, like configuration and enode format?

Answer (score 0):

1. Datadir should be initialized first with network genesis.json (`./erigon init --datadir=... genesis.json`)
2. One or more known node enode addresses should be used as bootnodes in erigon arguments

Related links:
https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon/issues/6747
https://notes.ethereum.org/@launchpad/kiln (go to Erigon section)